# Calculation of IRR

Tags: finance

How do we calculate IRR if I have an investment that allows me to buy into 10% of a company @1m and the first year is a negative cash flow of 200,000 but the subsequent years till year 10 is a positive cash flow of 300,000.

Comment: Hi Bobby, we're not going to do your homework if you show no effort. This type of question is also too basic for this site.

Comment: Hi Bob, thank you for your reply. My background is computer engineering and therefore I am asking this question because the guidelines that are provided online isnt very clear and thus I am asking this question.

Comment: There isn't really much similar solutions on the web pertaining to my question as all of the solutions provided are taking into consideration that the initial investment would be buying 100% of the the company and thus its straightforward calculating the IRR even with the different type of cash flow